# Sort and Search Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I have a datatable that has been bound to a Gridview in code behind. This means i would have to sort columns in code behind and when searching for a record i would imagine that would be done in code behind too.

The code i have to sort the gridview is

```
Private Function GetCustData As Datatable
Dim dt as new datatable

dt = GetDataFromBusinessLayer(CustomerID)
Return dt

End Function
```

And the code to sort

```
Private Sub gv_Sorting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles gv.Sorting
    If e.SortExpression = "Name" 
        gv.DataSource = GetCustData '.DefaultView.Sort = "Name" & "DESC"
        gv.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can tell i tried using .DefaultView.Sort = "Name" & "DESC" but this didnt work and got the error *Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource*. Searching around most are using Viewstate but that doesnt seem applicable in my case.

Can anyone advise how i would sort one/multiple columns?

In addition i will like to have a textbox which will search for the Name column. I think the above should suffice when it comes to it but if not could someone put me on the right track so i can work towards that now rather than having to change what im doing at a later stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your current code does not have a space. To sort by Name DESC your Sort string would need to be: "Name DESC".

To set the Sort string to multiple columns, just add a comma between each one, like this:

```
Dim dt as new datatable = GetCustData(1)
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Name DESC, FirstName ASC"
gv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
gv.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks. When i have the code under gv sorting event....
Handles gv.Sorting
        If e.SortExpression = "ID" Then
            GetCustData(1).DefaultView.Sort = "ID DESC"
            gv.DataSource = GetCustData(1).DefaultView
            gv.DataBind()
        End If

That doesnt show an error but at the same time it doesnt work?

Comment: @Computer - the GetCustData method calls the database every time. When you call it the second time (gv.DataSource = GetCustData(1).DefaultView) you are erasing the sort set in the line earlier. I will update my code sample to be more like what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a list of rows

```
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

and then when you have a list you can now use sort

```
list.OrederBy(c=>c.///specific value in your list)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Linq` to do the sort for you.

```
Dim dt as new datatable

dt = From dr as Datarow in GetDataFromBusinessLayer(CustomerID)
     Order by dr.item("First Sort field), dr.Item("Second Sort Field")
     Select dr

Return dt
```

... I did this without the IDE, but that should do the trick, I believe.

Here's one exmaple online - [Sorting DataTable with Linq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/linq-sorting-a-datatable.aspx)

Hope this helps.